# Is the following function tail recursive?

Tags: recursion, f#, tail-recursion

I have a function in which the starred line is a conjunction involving a recursive call.  As conjunctions work, if `h1 <> h2` then the recursive call will not be made.  But if the call is made, then will the compiler still backtrack and perform a whole bunch of conjunctions over `true` values?  Or will it elide this unnecessary step?

In other words, is the following function effectively tail recursive?

```
let isExtensionOf<'A when 'A : equality> (lst1 : list<'A>) (lst2 : list<'A>) : bool =
    let rec helper (currLst1 : list<'A>) (currLst2 : list<'A>) : bool =
        match currLst1, currLst2 with
        | h1 :: _, [] -> false
        | [], _ -> true
        | h1 :: t1, h2 :: t2 -> (h1 = h2) && (helper t1 t2) // *
    helper lst1 lst2
```

Yes, I know that the starred line should be written `if h1 = h2 then helper t1 t2 else false`.  But I am just curious.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Easiest way to answer these sort of questions: feed in a gigantic list which you think will trigger the pathological behaviour and see what happens.

Comment: I would rather compile it and then look at resulting code with ILSpy. More reliable. Also note that the result may differ depending on whether optimizations are enabled.

Comment: Well, it handled lists of cardinality `1,00,000,000` (one hundred million) without batting an eyelid, so I'll just assume that my question can be answered in the affirmative.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another easy trick to find out whether the function is tail-recursive is to throw an exception and look at the stack trace. For example, you can modify `helper` as follows:

```
let rec helper (currLst1 : list<'A>) (currLst2 : list<'A>) : bool =
    match currLst1, currLst2 with
    | h1 :: _, [] -> failwith "!"
    | [], _ -> failwith "!"
    | h1 :: t1, h2 :: t2 -> (h1 = h2) && (helper t1 t2)
```

If you now call `helper [1..10] [1..10]`, you get a stack trace that looks like this:

> System.Exception: !
>      at FSI_0002.helper[A](FSharpList'1 currLst1, FSharpList'1 currLst2) in test.fsx:line 4
>      at .$FSI_0003.main@()
>   Stopped due to error

But if you change the code to be non-tail-recursive - e.g. by modifying the last line to make the recursive call first `(helper t1 t2) && (h1 = h2)`, then the stack trace shows all the recursive calls:

> System.Exception: !
>      at FSI_0004.helper[A](FSharpList'1 currLst1, FSharpList'1 currLst2) in test.fsx:line 4
>      at FSI_0004.helper[A](FSharpList'1 currLst1, FSharpList'1 currLst2) in test.fsx:line 4
>      at FSI_0004.helper[A](FSharpList'1 currLst1, FSharpList'1 currLst2) in test.fsx:line 4
>      at FSI_0004.helper[A](FSharpList'1 currLst1, FSharpList'1 currLst2) in test.fsx:line 4
>      at FSI_0004.helper[A](FSharpList'1 currLst1, FSharpList'1 currLst2) in test.fsx:line 4
>      at FSI_0004.helper[A](FSharpList'1 currLst1, FSharpList'1 currLst2) in test.fsx:line 4
>      at FSI_0004.helper[A](FSharpList'1 currLst1, FSharpList'1 currLst2) in test.fsx:line 4
>      at FSI_0004.helper[A](FSharpList'1 currLst1, FSharpList'1 currLst2) in test.fsx:line 4
>      at FSI_0004.helper[A](FSharpList'1 currLst1, FSharpList'1 currLst2) in test.fsx:line 4
>      at FSI_0004.helper[A](FSharpList'1 currLst1, FSharpList'1 currLst2) in test.fsx:line 4
>      at FSI_0004.helper[A](FSharpList'1 currLst1, FSharpList'1 currLst2) in test.fsx:line 4
>      at .$FSI_0005.main@()

Comment: If I don't miss something such method would work in Release mode only. In Debug mode tail call optimization is disabled (I mean Generate tail calls tailcheckbox in properties). In Debug mode this checkbox is unchecked by default.

Answer (score 6):

From ILSpy it would appear so:

```
    IL_0000: nop
    IL_0001: newobj instance void class '<StartupCode$ConsoleApplication3>.$Program'/helper@10<!!A>::.ctor()
    IL_0006: stloc.0
    IL_0007: ldloc.0
    IL_0008: ldarg.1
    IL_0009: ldarg.2
    IL_000a: tail.
    IL_000c: call !!0 class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2<class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.FSharpList`1<!!A>, class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.FSharpList`1<!!A>>::InvokeFast<bool>(class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2<!0, class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2<!1, !!0>>, !0, !1)
    IL_0011: ret
```